# How can I output the values aligned to each column name?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace freewritings
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> numlist = new List<int>() { 35, 30, 10, 5, 15,25, 20, 40 };

            Console.Write("Original List\t");
            Console.Write("Sorted List\t");

            foreach(var num in numlist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Original List    Sorted List
35               5
30               10
10               15
5                20
15               25 
25               30
20               35
40               40
```

Comment: Is your question about sorting or displaying output? You need to specify a single issue and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of that problem.

Comment: My question is displaying the output aligned with each column name. Like for example I have 3 columns ("Original List, "Sorted List", "Inserted List"). I want to output each values aligned with the column names.

Comment: Then why is it that your expected output includes data that isn't even in the code? If you expect to output a sorted list then you have to have a sorted list to output. Based on what you've posted, you're expecting us to provide that data as well, so your question is incomplete.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162855/c-sharp-console-columns-formatting-and-positioning

Comment: @finnmorphy: you have two answers now, Do any of them meet your needs?  You can accept one answer, and/or you can upvote any answers that are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `string.Format` and interpolated strings allow you to specify spacing and alignment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#control-spacing

In this case, I'm aligning within a 15 character span (since "Original List" has 13 characters).  I also added a few characters to the header line to make it look pretty.  I also aligned it to the right (so that the ones and tens line up as expected):

```
var numlist = new List<int>() { 35, 30, 10, 5, 15, 25, 20, 40 };
var sorted = numlist.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
var reverse = numlist.OrderByDescending(x=>x).ToList();

const string heading1 = "Original List";
const string heading2 = "Sorted List";
const string heading3 = "Reverse Sort";
Console.WriteLine($"       {heading1,15} {heading2,15} {heading3,15}");

for(var i = 0; i < numlist.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{numlist[i],15} {sorted[i],15} {reverse[i],15}");
}
```

The output from this looks like:

```
     Original List     Sorted List    Reverse Sort
         35               5              40
         30              10              35
         10              15              30
          5              20              25
         15              25              20
         25              30              15
         20              35              10
         40              40               5
```

I've added a 3rd column.  You can vary the spacing (say to more or less than 15 characters per column) if appropriate.  You can play with this to get it to look exactly what you want.

One thing to note is that if you use a negative number as the alignment specification, say:

```
Console.WriteLine($"       {heading1,-15} {heading2,-15} {heading3,-15}");
```

The the field ends up left-aligned rather than right aligned.  I'm a big fan of right-alignment for numbers.  Again, feel free to play around with this code.

Answer (score 0):

A good ol'e fashioned `for` loop is a good option here

```
var numlist = new List<int>() { 35, 30, 10, 5, 15, 25, 20, 40 };
var sortedlist = numlist.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();

Console.Write("Original List\t");
Console.WriteLine("Sorted List");

for (int i = 0; i < numlist.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{numlist[i]}\t{sortedlist[i]}");
}
```